# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier Jquery

Tags: javascript

I tested this javascript in Chrome's Javascript console and it returned `SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier`.

I got this code from a tutorial and was just testing Chrome's console so i expected it to work, unless I'm using the console wrong?

```
$('#regform').submit(function (evt) {
evt.preventDefault();
console.log("reADY FOR SENNDING POST REQ TO  REGISTERMS.PHP");

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'registerms.php',
        data: $('#regform').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
        }
        error: function()
        {

        }
      });
```

Comment: Does the page you're testing on have a link to the jquery library?

Comment: Yes, it is there.

Comment: are you missing a   }   at the end?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#regform').submit(function (evt) {
evt.preventDefault();
  console.log("reADY FOR SENNDING POST REQ TO  REGISTERMS.PHP");

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'registerms.php',
    data: $('#regform').serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);


    ////////////////////////////////
    },   <--- Missing ','
    ///////////////////////////////



    error: function()
    {

    }
  });
```